# Use SQL to display count of min and count of max within group

Tags: sql, ms-access, correlated-subquery

## Goal

I am looking for a way to count the number of items that are equal to the min or max of a group. I have items that are received every few days and are entered bi-weekly. I need to see the Min and Max ReceivedDate for each EntryDate, and the Count of items at the Min and at the Max. Using SQL in MS Access.

## Input

```
tblItem

|    EntryDate    |   ReceivedDate   |
--------------------------------------
|   01/01/2016    |    16/12/2015    |
|   01/01/2016    |    15/12/2015    |
|   01/01/2016    |    10/12/2015    |
|   01/01/2016    |    10/12/2015    |
|   01/01/2016    |    10/12/2015    |
|   01/01/2016    |    10/12/2015    |
|   15/01/2016    |    05/01/2016    |
|   15/01/2016    |    05/01/2016    |
|   15/01/2016    |    04/01/2016    |
|   15/01/2016    |    03/01/2016    |
|   15/01/2016    |    03/01/2016    |
|   15/01/2016    |    03/01/2016    |
```

## Current Query

```
SELECT tblItem.EntryDate, 
Min(tblItem.ReceivedDate) AS MinReceivedDate, 
Max(tblItem.ReceivedDate) AS MaxReceivedDate
FROM tblItem
GROUP BY tblItem.EntryDate;
```

## Current Output

```
Query1

| EntryDate  | MinReceivedDate | MaxReceivedDate |
--------------------------------------------------
| 01/01/2016 |    10/12/2015   |   16/12/2015    |
| 15/01/2016 |    03/01/2016   |   05/01/2016    |
```

## Desired Output

```
Query1

| EntryDate  | MinReceivedDate | CountOfMin | MaxReceivedDate | CountOfMax |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 01/01/2016 |    10/12/2015   |      4     |   16/12/2015    |      1     |
| 15/01/2016 |    03/01/2016   |      3     |   05/01/2016    |      2     |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if MS Access allows subqueries like this. If this doesn't work, please let me know and I'll delete the answer. Otherwise though:

```
SELECT
    SQ.EntryDate,
    SQ.MinReceivedDate,
    SUM(IIF(I.ReceivedDate = SQ.MinReceivedDate, 1, 0)) AS CountOfMin,
    SQ.MaxReceivedDate,
    SUM(IIF(I.ReceivedDate = SQ.MaxReceivedDate, 1, 0)) AS CountOfMax
FROM (
    SELECT
        SQI.EntryDate,
        MIN(SQI.ReceivedDate) AS MinReceivedDate,
        MAX(SQI.ReceivedDate) AS MaxReceivedDate
    FROM
        tblItem SQI
    GROUP BY
        SQI.EntryDate
    ) SQ
INNER JOIN tblItem I ON I.EntryDate = SQ.EntryDate
GROUP BY
    SQ.EntryDate,
    SQ.MinReceivedDate,
    SQ.MaxReceivedDate
```

Comment: I get the following error message: _Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'SUM(CASE WHEN I.DateReceived = SQ.MinReceivedDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 End)'._

Comment: It looks like Access doesn't support the `CASE` statement, but I found the correct function for it. I'll update that now.