# Oracle - How to Show Total Number of [Apartments] with Min/Max Rate (Nested Aggregate Functions Issue)

Tags: oracle11g, max, aggregate-functions, min

I'm wanting to discover the simplest/least performance intensive approach to show within a row of data to how many records within the group match the Min/Max rates within the data that is being grouped.  In my example buildings are being grouped.

In the pseudo code I provided, along with the existing columns I'm also wanting to provide two more columns that show how many apartments within each building have rates that match the min/max rates within each building.  Intuitively I thought that all I was needing to do was count each occurrence where the apartment rate matched either the Min/Max rate of the group.  The issue here is that I'm now nesting Aggregate Functions and that is not working out.  Perhaps I'm missing something simple.

In this version of the query (Pseudo Code is Much simpler than my actual code) I could just wrap the query and then use the Min/Max values to compare against the street rates in an outer query but I'm looking for a simple approach perhaps as simply as my pseudo code if I was able to nest MIN(rate) within the CASE and SUM().  Outside of making this query complex I'm not sure of a simple approach.

The specific line that does not work is `LINE 20: SUM(CASE WHEN rate = MIN(rate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_min_rates`.  I have it commented out.

```
WITH rates AS
(
  SELECT 1001 AS apt_Key, 5  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1002 AS apt_Key, 4  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1003 AS apt_Key, 17 AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1004 AS apt_Key, 10 AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1005 AS apt_Key, 4  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1006 AS apt_Key, 7  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1007 AS apt_Key, 5  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1008 AS apt_Key, 13 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1009 AS apt_Key, 10 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1010 AS apt_Key, 13 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1011 AS apt_Key, 8  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual
) /* END rates CTE */

SELECT COUNT(apt_key) AS tot_apts, building
  , ROUND(AVG(rate),1) AS avg_rate
  , MIN(rate) AS min_rate
  , MAX(rate) AS max_rate  
  -- SUM(CASE WHEN rate = MIN(rate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_min_rates  
FROM rates
GROUP BY building
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell there just doesn't appear to be a way to get this to work within the same simple query without using sub selects or virtual tables or a CTE.  Trying to do rate = MAX(rate) just isn't recognized by SQL.  From what I can tell no database engine plays nice when you attempt to do this.  Bummer.

The link below that I found is for MS ACCESS but it's the same issue.

[Use SQL to display count of min and count of max within group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586959/use-sql-to-display-count-of-min-and-count-of-max-within-group)

While the solution in the above link works I prefer the ease of readability and reuse of Common Table Expressions (CTEs) to organize my queries and the solution I am using is below.

```
WITH rates AS
(
  SELECT 1001 AS apt_Key, 5  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1002 AS apt_Key, 4  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1003 AS apt_Key, 17 AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1004 AS apt_Key, 10 AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1005 AS apt_Key, 4  AS rate, 120 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1006 AS apt_Key, 7  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1007 AS apt_Key, 5  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1008 AS apt_Key, 13 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1009 AS apt_Key, 10 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1010 AS apt_Key, 13 AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1011 AS apt_Key, 8  AS rate, 130 AS building FROM dual
) /* END rates CTE */

/* Use the below to extract the min/max values per Group aka Building in this case */
, building_min_max AS
(
SELECT building, MIN(rate) AS min_rate, MAX(rate) AS max_rate, ROUND(AVG(rate), 1) AS avg_rate
FROM rates
GROUP BY building
)

/* Using a Detailed view mark each max and min rate so we can sum the up later */
SELECT COUNT(apt_key) AS tot_apts, r.building
  , ROUND(AVG(rate), 1) AS avg_rate
  , MIN(rate) AS min_rate
  , MAX(rate) AS max_rate
  , SUM(CASE WHEN r.rate = mm.min_rate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_min_rates
  , SUM(CASE WHEN r.rate = mm.max_rate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_max_rates
FROM rates r
  JOIN building_min_max mm ON mm.building = r.building
GROUP BY r.building
;
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is just a placeholder to show that it is not possible.